# Como adicionar o Reliese/Laravel no provider em Lumen/Laravel, última versão?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Acabei de instalar o Lumen e vou precisar usar o [Reliese](https://github.com/reliese/laravel) para criar os Models (e as migrations) a partir de uma uma base de dados que já existe.

Seguindo a documentação, apos a instalação eu preciso adicionar o Reliese no provider em Config/app.php

O problema é que não existe Config/app.php em Lumen.

Eu tentei adicionar em app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php

```
public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
            $this->app->register(\Reliese\Coders\CodersServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
```

e rodei o comando `php artisan code:models --table=users`

E esse é o erro que apresenta;

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to undefined function Reliese\Coders\config_path()
```

O meu Env está apontando para local  `APP_ENV=local`.

Alguém sabe como adicionar esse classe no service provider ou como fazer funcionar o Reliese no Lumen?

Comment: Esse pacote não é compativel com em `Lumen/Laravel`, talvez precisa trocar de pacote, ou então abrir um issue para verificar a compatibilidade e se já tem projetos compativeis, esse primeiro erro por exemplo é um função `helper` que tem no Laravel, no Lumen precisa fazer!

Comment: ok. Bom saber. vou ver uma outra solucao